# AngularJS v1.5.5 two way binding doesn't work with service

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am trying to retrieve an share data from a resource via an angular service, please see code of the service below:

```
    (function(){var app = angular.module('geoProApp');
    app.factory('project', ['$resource','$log',
        function ($resource,$log) {
            var res = $resource('http://localhost/api/project/:id', { id: '@id' }, {
                queryPaged: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    isArray: false,
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    url: 'http://localhost/api/project/paged',
                },
                //ignore that for now
                update: { method: 'PUT' }
            });
            var currentData = {
                totalItems:0,
                projects:[]
            };
$log.log('initial value');
            $log.log(currentData);
            return {
                queryPaged: function (params) {
                    return res.queryPaged(null, params).$promise.then(function (response) {
                        currentData.totalItems =response.total; 
                        currentData.projects=response.result;
                        $log.log('after data retrieval in service');
                        $log.log(currentData);
                        return response;
                    })
                },  
                data: currentData
            }
        }]);
}());
```

In the controller using the service, I want to bind to the data, like this:

```
app.controller('projectList', function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, $log, $http, auth, project, filter, users, bsLoadingOverlayService) {
 ....
    $scope.totalItems = project.data.totalItems;
    $scope.projects = project.data.projects;

    project.queryPaged(helpers.setPagingParams($scope.currentPage, $scope.itemsPerPage, filter)).then(function () {

        $log.log('success callback exposed by service');
        $log.log(project.data);
        $log.log('bound values')
        $log.log($scope.totalItems);
        $log.log($scope.projects);
....
    });
```

However, it seems that bound variables `$scope.totalItems` and `$scope.projects` never get updated, even tho the service retrieves new data, which can be seen here:

[output of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05qCP.png)

Can someone point me in the right direction what I might be missing?

Comment: you should keep $scope.totalItems = project.data.totalItems;
    $scope.projects = project.data.projects; inside project.queryPaged functions .

Comment: Maybe i should explain further, my intention is to retrieve the data only once and share it via the service between multiple controllers through the return value `data`. If an update of the data is needed, i can make a call to `project.queryPaged(..)`. Everthing works fine, except that the values returned through `data` are never updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular isn't very fond of using primitive datatypes directly. The two way binding doesn't work as expected. Instead of setting the controller scope like this

```
$scope.totalItems = project.data.totalItems;
$scope.projects = project.data.projects;
```

I would instead have an object like this.

```
$scope.model = project.data;
```

Read this [article](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) that explains why the two way binding doesn't work with primitive types.

A good quote from the article is...

> always have a '.' in your ng-models  ... Having a '.' in your models
>   will ensure that prototypal inheritance is in play. So, use  `<input type="text" ng-model="someObj.prop1">`

Comment: I have tried as you suggested, the outcome is still the same. 

`Object {totalItems: 0, projects: 0}`

Comment: try mapping the data object directly to the model. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Wow, that really did the trick! Thank you!  But why does it work this way? I suspecting there is some scope and inheritance witchcraft under the hood, but i really would like to know how this works exactly. Otherwise i see my self cargo cult programming everthing in an object if it doesn't bind...

Comment: i edited my answer and included an article that explains why it doesn't work

Comment: Great. Have fun with more angular coding!